# : Error response from daemon: Invalid container name ('activemq'), only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed

Tags: windows, docker

Running Docker desktop on windows.

```
docker run --name='activemq' -it --rm -P webcenter/activemq:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: Invalid container name ('activemq'), only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

As you may see, 'activemq' fits the allowed mask. What could be the reason.I'm forced to run it just without the name explicitly set.

The Docker details are below:

```
docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.31
 Version:           20.10.23
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.10
 Git commit:        7155243
 Built:             Thu Jan 19 17:43:10 2023
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.17.0 (99724)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.23
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.10
  Git commit:       6051f14
  Built:            Thu Jan 19 17:32:04 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.18
  GitCommit:        2456e983eb9e37e47538f59ea18f2043c9a73640
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running on Windows which comes with a weird shell. Try removing the single quotes which serve no purpose.